# Incomming call broadcast receivernot working in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat, incoming-call

I have an incomming call Broadcast receiver, it is working on android 7.1 nut not on android 4.2.

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MainActivity activity;
    public static final String PREFS_PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String PREFS_EMAIL = "Email";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),0);
        if(settings.contains(PREFS_EMAIL)) {
            if (extras != null) {
                String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", state);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                    User user;
                    String phone = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                    try {
                        user = db.getUserByPhone(phone);
                        Log.d("USER", user.getEmail());
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, FloatingActivity.class)
                                .putExtra("PHONE", TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
                        String phoneNumber = extras
                                .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        settings.edit().putString(PREFS_PHONE, phone).apply();
                        Log.d("MY_DEBUG_TAG", phoneNumber);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        Log.i(phone, "Not Found!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Floating activity

```
public class FloatingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.chathead_layout);

        startService(new Intent(this, FloatingViewService.class)
                .putExtra("PHONE", this.getIntent().getStringExtra("PHONE")));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Floating Service

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {

    private View chatHead;
    private View closeChatHead;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    private String phone;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private boolean mayRemove;
    private Rect chatHeadRect;
    private Rect closeHeadRect;
    private boolean isHover;

    public static final String PREFS_PHONE = "Phone";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Inflate the floating view layout we created
        settings = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),0);
        phone = settings.getString(PREFS_PHONE, null);
        User user = db.getUserByPhone(phone);

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.chathead_layout, null);
        closeChatHead = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.close_chathead_layout, null);

        closeChatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Add the view to the window.
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        //Specify the view position
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 500;

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params2 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params2.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER;

        //Add the view to the window
        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
        windowManager.addView(closeChatHead, params2);

        ((CircleImageView) chatHead.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)).setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#"+user.getColour())));

        ((TextView) chatHead.findViewById(R.id.pts)).setText(user.getPts()+"");

        switch (user.getDirection()) {
            case 1:
                chatHead.findViewById(R.id.up).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

            case 0:
                chatHead.findViewById(R.id.equal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

            case -1:
                chatHead.findViewById(R.id.down).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }

        final CircleImageView remover = ((CircleImageView) chatHead.findViewById(R.id.remover));

        //Set the close button
        /*ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) chatHead.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //close the service and remove the from from the window
                stopSelf();
            }
        });*/

        //Drag and move floating view using user's touch action.
        chatHead.findViewById(R.id.chat_head).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //remember the initial position.
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;

                        //get the touch location
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                        closeChatHead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //show remover

                        //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                        //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);

                        int[] a = new int[2];
                        int[] b = new int[2];

                        chatHead.getLocationOnScreen(a);
                        View remover = closeChatHead.findViewById(R.id.remover);
                        remover.getLocationOnScreen(b);

                        chatHeadRect = new Rect(a[0], a[1], a[0] + chatHead.getWidth(), a[1] + chatHead.getHeight());
                        closeHeadRect = new Rect(b[0], b[1], b[0] + remover.getWidth(), b[1] + remover.getHeight());

                        if (checkToRemove(Math.round((chatHeadRect.left)) + Math.round((chatHeadRect.width()) / 2),
                                Math.round((chatHeadRect.top)) + Math.round((chatHeadRect.height()) / 2),
                                closeHeadRect.left, closeHeadRect.top, closeHeadRect.left + closeHeadRect.width())) {

                            //Log.d("motion move","intersect = yes");
                            mayRemove = true;
                            if (!isHover) {
                                isHover = !isHover;

                                windowManager.removeView(closeChatHead);

                                closeChatHead = LayoutInflater.from(FloatingViewService.this).inflate(R.layout.close_chathead_layout, null);

                                windowManager.addView(closeChatHead, params2);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //Log.d("motion move","intersect = no");
                            mayRemove = false;
                            if (isHover) {
                                //Log.d("MOTION MOVE2","PASSOU");
                                isHover = !isHover;

                                windowManager.removeView(closeChatHead);

                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                closeChatHead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.close_chathead_layout, null);

                                windowManager.addView(closeChatHead, params2);
                            }
                        }
                        closeChatHead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        int Xdiff = (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        int Ydiff = (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                        //The check for Xdiff <10 && YDiff< 10 because sometime elements moves a little while clicking.
                        //So that is click event.
                        if (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(FloatingViewService.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);

                                //close the service and remove view from the view hierarchy
                                stopSelf();
                        }

                        if (mayRemove) {
                            stopSelf();
                        }

                        closeChatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


  if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}

private boolean checkToRemove(int x,int y,int left,int top,int left_width){
    return (y>(top-50) && x>(left-50) && x<(left_width-50));
}
```

}

Why not working:

In 7.1 everything is working fine i get the call and the chathead apears.

In 4.4 [LG] I receive the call but nothing happens.

In 4.4 [BQ] Aplication crashes.

Any help?

Comment: Did you get any crash logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Where I'm calling startActivity from outside an activity like:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, FloatingActivity.class)
                                .putExtra("PHONE", TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
```

in android 4.4 it is required to set the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

o in all ocurrencies i need to call it like:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, FloatingActivity.class)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    .putExtra("PHONE", TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
```